# Aggregating on dependent columns

Tags: sql, database

I have a table like this

```
IDX       IDY   ColX ColY ...
------------------------------
idx1      idy1
idx1      idy1
idx1      idy1
idx2      idy4
idx2      idy4
idx3      idy1
idx3      idy1
idx3      idy1
idx3      idy1
...       ...
...       ...
```

So for each unique IDX there is one IDY. I need the count of IDYs across unique IDXs.
ie., I need

```
Count       IDY
---------------
2           idy1 (1 for idx1s and 1 for idx3s)
1           idy4 (1 for idx2s)
...
```

Can I do this in one query ? How ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    IDY, Count(DISTINCT IDX) As IDXCount
FROM
    TableName
Group BY
    IDY
```